# android widget button crashes

Tags: android, android-widget

i am doing a widget that has 3 buttons. i need to call a function for every button. i am doing like this:

```
public class myWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
    } else {
  // check, if our Action was called
         if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
                String msg = "null";
                try {
                    msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");

                    if(msg.equals("nextpage"))
                        callFunction1();

                    if(msg.equals("prevpage"))
                                       callFunction2();

                    if(msg.equals("ref")) 
                                         callfunction3();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                }
         }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ) {



    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, SteauaWidget.class);

    Intent active = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    active.putExtra("msg", "ref");

    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, active, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, actionPendingIntent);

    Intent nextPage = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
    nextPage.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    nextPage.putExtra("msg", "nextpage");

    PendingIntent pendingNextPage = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, nextPage, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingNextPage);

    Intent prevPage = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
    prevPage.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    prevPage.putExtra("msg", "prevpage");

    PendingIntent pendingPrevPage = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 3, prevPage, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingPrevPage);


}
```

but my widget crashes with this message in the logcat:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver my.widget.MyWidget: java.lang.NullPointerException

what is the problem?

Comment: Can you tell me what line the null pointer is?  Post the actual logcat.  If there is nothing there, I would put LOG messages in and see where it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Kaediil is right, you've got to narrow down the failure point by placing Log.d() statements throughout your code. I see quite a few places where a pointer could still be null and thus throwing the error. The line:
thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, SteauaWidget.class);
looks weird. Also, since the error specifically mentions
my.widget.MyWidget it stands to reason that MyWidget.class is not getting instantiated correctly or isn't given time to finish loading thus producing the following NullPointerException.